# Showing strong continuity using weak continuity and continuity of the norm function

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, weak-convergence

We have a weakly continuous function $f$ from $[0,T]$ into a separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, i.e., 
$$
\left[t_n \to t\right] \implies \left[\ell\left(f\left(t_n\right)\right) \to \ell\left(f\left(t\right)\right)\right]
$$
for which the map $[0,T] \to [0,\infty) : t \mapsto \left\|f(t)\right\|_{\mathcal{H}}$ is continuous. Now we would like to show that it is also norm continuous into $\mathcal{H}$, so
$$
\left[t_n \to t\right] \implies \left[\left\|f\left(t_n\right)-f(t)\right\|_{\mathcal{H}} \to 0\right],
$$
in easy notition.

If we assume that the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ is finite-dimensional, we are done, so we will assume that the Hilbert space (which is assumed to be separable) is countably infinite dimensional.

I tried the following argument, which did not really yield the results I was hoping for: for every $n$, by Hahn-Banach, there exists a functional $\ell_n\in\mathcal{H}^{*}$ (with operator norm 1) such that 
$$
\ell_n\left(f\left(t_n\right)-f(t)\right) =\left\|f\left(t_n\right)-f(t)\right\|_{\mathcal{H}}.
$$
Using the linearity of $\ell_n$, we see that $\left\|f\left(t_n\right)-f(t)\right\|_{\mathcal{H}} = \ell_n\left(f\left(t_n\right)\right)-\ell_n\left(f(t)\right)$.

With the same argument, there exists an $\ell\in\mathcal{H}^{*}$ such that $\ell(f(t)) = \left\|f(t)\right\|_{\mathcal{H}}$, and, for every $n$, a functional $\hat{\ell}_n\in\mathcal{H}^{*}$ such that $\hat{\ell}_n(f(t_n)) = \left\|f(t_n)\right\|_{\mathcal{H}}$. Then, by "adding zero" twice, we find
\begin{align*}
\left\|f\left(t_n\right)-f(t)\right\|_{\mathcal{H}} &= \ell_n\left(f\left(t_n\right)\right)-\ell_n\left(f(t)\right)\\
&= \ell_n\left(f\left(t_n\right)\right) - \hat{\ell}_n(f(t_n)) +\hat{\ell}_n(f(t_n)) - \ell(f(t)) + \ell(f(t))-\ell_n\left(f(t)\right).
\end{align*}
Using the assumption of the continuity of the map $t \mapsto \left\|f(t)\right\|_{\mathcal{H}}$, the third term converges to the fourth one if $n$ rises to infinity, so I thought of showing

1. $\lim_{n\to\infty}\ell_n\left(f\left(t_n\right)\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \hat{\ell}_n(f(t_n))$
2. $\lim_{n\to\infty}\ell_n\left(f(t)\right) = \ell(f(t))$

but this has not yet been fruitful. I tried using the boundedness of the sequence $\left\{\left\|f(t_n)\right\|:n\geq1\right\}$ and using the reflexivity of $\mathcal H$ to obtain these results, but with these assumptions, I can not reach the conclusion.

Then again, this might not be the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So writing $x_n = f(t_n)$, $x = f(t)$ for brevity, we have $x_n \to x$ weakly and $\|x_n\| \to \|x\|$, and we want $x_n \to x$ in norm.

This is generally true in any Hilbert space.  Hint:

$$\|x_n - x\|^2 = \|x_n\|^2 - 2 \operatorname{Re} \langle x_n, x \rangle + \|x\|^2.$$

Weak convergence tells you something about the middle term.

(To get here from your idea, note that you never really need Hahn-Banach in a Hilbert space: the desired linear functional $\ell_n$ is explicitly just a scalar multiple of $y \mapsto \langle y, f(t_n) - f(t) \rangle$.)

Comment: Ah, indeed, we are working on a real Hilbert space here, so the middle is just applying weak continuity with the functional $\langle \cdot, x \rangle$.  Thanks, that was indeed pretty straight-forward.